# Messaging and Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to wrap my head around messaging in Jupyter notebooks. But I'm a bit lost and confused.

My goal is fairly straight forward to state: I want my python kernel to update the output of a cell in a Jupyter notebook while a long calculation is running. Whenever new data arrives in the browser, I want to trigger a redraw by calling some javascript function.

Specifically, the cell output contains HTML with a WebGL canvas. That part works well. I can easily visualize the initial data in the canvas with WebGL/javascript. But I want to update the data dynamically, as the kernel performs a long calculation on it. What I'd like to know is how one of my javascript functions in a notebook can receive binary data from my kernel.

I tried to [read the documentation](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture/how_jupyter_ipython_work.html#notebooks) on messaging and jupyter notebooks, but it's really short and doesn't provide any links for further reading. What would really help is an example in the form of two code snippets, one for the notebook and the other for the kernel side.

Comment: Dislaying Javascript (`IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Javascript('//js code'))`) will execute that Javascript in the frontend. With a unique ID for your original output, it should be possible to use that to modify it. The more advanced way is for your initial displayed object to set up a Comm object, which is like a socket to communicate with the kernel. Unfortunately, we don't seem to have any docs on how to do this at present, but if you want to dig into it, ipywidgets is the main user of comms.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to look at ipywidgets.