# Distinguish iPython in HTML browser vs console

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

iPython can be run either in an interactive mode in a console, or as part of a Jupyter HTML notebook with richer capabilities, e.g. ability to render HTML components... etc.

I'm writing a Jupyter extension that exposes an API returning a list of objects, and I want this API to return rendered HTML if inside a browser, otherwise a list of strings for text-based consoles. Is there a way to tell what the current iPython environment (text-only or HTML)?

Answer (score 0):

[Messaging and Jupyter Notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352628/messaging-and-jupyter-notebooks)

https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html#messages-on-the-iopub-pub-sub-channel

> This data is published to all frontends. Each message can have multiple representations of the data; it is up to the frontend to decide which to use and how. A single message should contain all possible representations of the same information. Each representation should be a JSON’able data structure, and should be a valid MIME type.

Looks like you should send both the HTML and list of strings, each marked as the correct MIME type, and let the display front end choose which to display.

Both links mention a `Comm` object which appears to set up a one on one link between kernel and front end. The `IOPub` channel is one to many.